# How to get term by name if the term is child of another one?

Tags: wordpress, hierarchy, taxonomy-terms

I could get term by a function

```
get_term_by( 'name', 'Test', 'my-taxonomy' )
```

Taxonomy terms structure is

level 1 --> Test

level 2 --> Test

Test

How to get term if the term is child of level 1 term?

Need to get `level 1 -> Test`

And which term I get with my snippet?

*level 1 -> Test*

*or
level 2 -> Test*

or
*Test?*

```
get_term_by( 'name', 'Test', 'my-taxonomy' )
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you look for but it will guide you through

With `get_term_by( 'name', 'Test', 'my-taxonomy' )` what you get is child term

That means from `level 1 -> Test` you get `Test`

If you want to get the parent term of test you can use `get_term($child_term_id, 'my-taxonomy');`

**Your code should be like this:**

```
$child_term = get_term_by( 'name', 'Test', 'my-taxonomy' );

$parent_term = get_term( $child_term->parent, 'my-taxonomy' );
```

You can `var_dump $child_term & $parent_term` to check the results

****You can also try with***

```
get_term_parents_list( $child_term->term_id, 'my-taxonomy' )
```